# Simple graphics library from Sparkle

Tags: rust, graphics

The [`piston2d-graphics`](https://crates.io/crates/piston2d-graphics) crate provides a trait, [`Graphics`](https://docs.rs/piston2d-graphics/0.36.0/graphics/trait.Graphics.html), which allows easy access to some graphics primitives. This would be a nice, easy-to-use API, if it weren't such a pain to end up with something that *implements* `Graphics`; for a time, there wasn't even a consistent set of crates that let you get one (that rendered anything to the screen, anyway).

I worked out a way of getting to a `Graphics`-implementing `struct` by the successive creation of six objects which take references to each other (one a `Builder`, so really five). This was still too convoluted for my needs, though, so I cracked out the Rustonomicon and simplified the interface down to:

```
use graphics::Graphics;

mod display;

fn main() {
    let mut d = display::Display::new();

    loop {
        let mut f = d.frame();
        let mut g = f.graphics();

        // g implements Graphics; do something with it
        g.clear_color([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]);

        f.commit().unwrap();
    }
}
```

I'm looking for suggestions for improving [the `display` module](https://codeberg.org/wizzwizz4/sparkle/src/commit/bbde54f614ab2c933206fd3dd6c1ffe285858fee/src/display.rs) and its API; I'm looking to making it a separate crate to use in other projects, but I want it to be good first.

---

`display.rs`:

```
use glutin::event_loop::EventLoop;
use glium_graphics::{Glium2d, GliumGraphics, OpenGL};
use glium::{backend::glutin::Display as GDisplay, Frame as GFrame};
pub use graphics::Graphics;

use core::pin::Pin;
use core::mem::drop;
use core::mem::ManuallyDrop;
use core::ptr::NonNull;

const OPENGL_VERSION: OpenGL = OpenGL::V4_5;

// I can't just use owning_ref because these don't deref.
pub struct Display {
    el: *mut EventLoop<()>,
    gdisplay: *mut GDisplay,
    g2d: ManuallyDrop<Glium2d>
}

pub struct Frame<'d, 's> {
    graphics: ManuallyDrop<GliumGraphics<'d, 's, GFrame>>,
    frame: Option<NonNull<GFrame>>
}

impl Display {
    pub fn new() -> Display {
        let wb = glutin::window::WindowBuilder::new()
            .with_title("Sparkle")
            .with_inner_size(glutin::dpi::PhysicalSize::new(800.0, 600.0));
        let cb = glutin::ContextBuilder::new();
        let el = Box::into_raw(Box::new(EventLoop::new()));
        let gdisplay = Box::into_raw(Box::new(GDisplay::new(
            wb, cb, unsafe { &*el }
        ).unwrap()));
        let g2d = glium_graphics::Glium2d::new(
            OPENGL_VERSION, unsafe { &*gdisplay }
        );

        Display {
            el: el,
            gdisplay: gdisplay,
            g2d: ManuallyDrop::new(g2d),
        }
    }

    #[must_use]
    pub fn frame<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Frame<'a, 'a> {
        let gdisplay = unsafe { &*self.gdisplay };
        let mut frame = Box::into_raw(Box::new(gdisplay.draw()));
        let graphics = GliumGraphics::new(
            &mut self.g2d, unsafe { &mut *frame }
        );
        Frame {
            graphics: ManuallyDrop::new(graphics),
            frame: NonNull::new(frame)
        }
    }

    pub fn event_loop<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a EventLoop<()> {
        // An immutable reference is okay, but there's
        // another immutable reference to el (in self.gdisplay)
        // so a mutable reference is right out.
        unsafe { &*self.el }
    }
}

impl Drop for Display {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            // The order matters! Each references the next, so they
            // must be dropped in that order to prevent use-after-free.
            ManuallyDrop::drop(&mut self.g2d);
            drop(Box::from_raw(self.gdisplay));
            drop(Box::from_raw(self.el));
        }
    }
}

impl<'d, 's> Frame<'d, 's> {
    pub fn commit(mut self) -> Result<(), glium::SwapBuffersError> {
        // SEE ALSO: The Drop implementation.
        unsafe {
            // self.graphics is using self.frame; must drop it first.
            ManuallyDrop::drop(&mut self.graphics);
            // Now we can take it out of the box.
            // Note that self.frame is always Some(_), because this
            // function is the only thing that sets it to None.
            Box::from_raw(self.frame.unwrap().as_ptr())
        }.finish()?;
        self.frame = None;  // setting H2G2 flag for the Drop trait impl
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn graphics(&mut self) -> &mut GliumGraphics<'d, 's, GFrame> {
        &mut self.graphics
    }
}

impl Drop for Frame<'_, '_> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // SEE ALSO: The .commit() implementation.
        match self.frame {
            Some(_) => panic!(concat!("sparkle::display::Frame must not ",
                                      "be dropped! .commit() instead")),
            None => ()  // Already cleaned up resources;
                        // let Rust free the struct.
        };
    }
}
```